# Use informations in TXT file in WSH JScript (Source , path , destination)

Tags: text, jscript, wsh

I am a beginner in JScript , i did a program to remove a file from folder to another in JScript , but each time i need to change those path if i gave it to another person it depends on their path in their computer. So they ask me to do a txt file which they change only the informations below and then the JScript will change either .

enter code here

the JScript  :

```
MoveFile2Desktop(filespec)

{var fso;
   fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
   fso.MoveFile(filespec, "c:\\windows\\desktop\\");
}
```

and i have a .txt file which contains

```
Source: P:\Desktop\name.txt
Destination : P:\Desktop\Folder1\name.txt
```

How can i read these 2 information and replace it in a JScript ?

Comment: Your code is JavaScript not VBScript.

Comment: Next time please Google first, I googled for "vbscript read text file" and got tons of valuable answers there. For example, check out the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198708.aspx)... - I'm not writing a real answer yet because it depends on your requirements of the TXT file. Will it always be exactly this format? Why is there a space before the second colon? And is the format flexible; could we change it to make the code simpler (e.g. just two lines with the paths, without "Source"/"Destination" text)?

Comment: Oh, oops, Noodles is right. It isn't even VBS. It's JScript. Well, even there you can find stuff in Google, e.g. [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t58aa4dd(v=vs.84).aspx). A little hint, you will mostly find browser-related things (which are much more limited) when you google for "JScript", the trick is to include "WSH" in your search query in Google which stands for "Windows Script Host", the environment you appear to be using.

Comment: Here's two lines from help to get the desktop folder `var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
         strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop");
`

Comment: @Noodles That really only works if they want the `desktop` folder, to be honest I think that is just an example. They want to store the source and destination in a file *(almost like an [INI file](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_ini.php))* and use that to power the script, like a custom config.

Comment: Yes it is exactly an ini file . The source and destination would always be the same .

Comment: @Lankymart it is an ini file . But the program that i told to do is in VBS not JScript .